# Pri la verbo "preni"

Tags: translation, verbs

Duolingo tradukas l'anglan frazon "What do you **take** in your coffee?" al "Kion vi **prenas** en via kafo?".

Mi havas 2 demandojn:

1. Laŭ la frazo, mi komprenas ke oni aldonas ion al sia kafo; do **kial Duo ne uzas unu el la verbojn "meti" aŭ "verŝi" anstataŭe?** Kio estas la diferenco de "preni ion al la kafo" kun "meti ion en la kafon" aŭ "verŝi ion en la kafon"?
2. **Kial Duo ne aldonas akuzativon al la "kafo"?** Ni scias ke oni faru tion por indiki la movadon de tio, kio oni aldonas ĝin en la kafo, tamen mi ne estas certa, ĉar tiel mi skribis antaŭe, ke mi ne komprenas la signifon de "preni ion al la kafo".

Answer (score 2):

Vi alportas ekzemplojn el Duolingo kvazaŭ ili estus aŭtoritataj. Sed ili ne estas.

Tiu supra frazo estas anglaĵo.

Oni povus demandi tion ĉi tiel:

```
Kion vi aldonas al kafo? / Kion vi kutime aldonas al via kafo?
```

Aŭ (kelkaj tradukoj, inter pluraj ebloj):

```
Ĉu vi aldonas ion al via kafo?
Kion mi metu en vian kafon?
Kion mi aldonu al via kafo?
```

La objekto estas tio, kion vi aldonas: *sukero*, *kremo*, ktp. Do, tiu objekto ricevas la `-n`. Tial ĝin ne ricevas *kafo*. Same kiel `mi algluas afiŝon al la muro` vi dirus `mi aldonas sukeron al (la) kafo`.

```
Kion vi aldonas al via kafo? Ĉu sukeron brunan, ĉu kremon?
```

Pro tio ke Duolingo ne estas aparte aŭtoritata fonto, kiam vi dubas, mi sugestas demandi pri via ebla traduko. Por multaj el ni, apero en Duolingo estas nur flanka informo, oni ne devas klarigi kial io malĝustas, eble tio simple malĝustas. Ni ne povas scii kial.

Vi ankaŭ povas klopodi traduki mem kaj demandi pri via traduko. Ĉar eĉ se Duolingo havas izolitan malĝustan frazon, pridiskuto ĉi tie ne tro helpos ilin (krom se vi iu planas revizii iliajn tekstojn surbaze de niaj diskutoj).

Comment: **en via kafo**, sen _-n_. Se vi celas _kion vi volas **meti** en vian kafon_, bonvolu aldoni la verbon _meti_, ĉar oni same facile povus supozi ke la eliziita verbo estas _havi_ kaj do la frazo estus _kion vi volas **havi** en via kafo_. Se ne temis pri elizio (ĉiuokaze riska afero en internacia komunikado) oni do ne povas aldoni la _-n_.

Comment: jes temis pri elizio, sed mi diras, ke dependas de kiel oni perceptas aferojn, ĉu oni uzas en + nominativo aŭ en + akuzativo. Mi pensas, ke estas movo de io al la kafo. Ĉiuokaze mi forigis mian komenton por ne konfuzu.

Comment: Dankon pro via respondo, Sinjoro @EduardoTrápani. Kelkfoje mi proponis miajn tradukojn de kelkaj frazoj al Duolingo, kaj Duo akceptis kelkajn de miaj proponoj kaj dankis min per retpoŝto :-)